# How do you mount a directory as a drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mount, virtual-drive

I have a directory on another drive that I want to show as a new virtual drive. How can I do that?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use the `subst` command:

```
subst X: F:\some\folder
```

There is also a great <strike>freeware</strike> paid utility called [**Visual Subst**](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html) to make things even easier:

[image]

**2021 Update:** that software is no longer freeware, and now costs 20$. The last free version is 1.0.6, which is still available on download websites such as Softonic and Uptodown.

Comment: yes I tried this before, but it doesnt auto-mount the dir on boot.

Comment: At the bottom of the application there is a checkbox **Apply virtual drives on Windows startup** if that's what you're after. You could also use a batch script with subst commands and place it in your startup folder.

Comment: I realize that the option is there, it just doesn't work.

probably because I have a space in the folder name (that I cant remove)

Comment: Possibly. There is also the startup folder in your start menu you can use. Make a batch script with subst commands in it and quote the paths with spaces. An example of 1 line would be `subst X: "C:\Program Files"`

Comment: Or add it as a run entry in the registry. It gets processed and the subst drive gets added quite early in the boot process then.

Comment: This utility indeed lets me mount a folder as a drive and it (or windows) assigns this new drive the same name as the drive where the source folder resides. When i try to rename that new drive, windows gives me an error about improper volume name. Is there any way i can fix this and have this new drive named the way i want?

Comment: Same question as Rusl: can we change the *virtual drive volume label*?

Comment: Use [`subst X: /d`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) to unmount it.

Answer (score 24):

I used the registry edit on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST#Persisting_across_reboots) so Windows would automaticaly create the drive when starting (tested on Windows 8.1):

1. Run **regedit**.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices`
3. Add a new **String Value** with the drive letter as the name

   - example: `X:`
4. Set the value using one of the following formats (Replace `C:\some\directory` with the folder path):

   - `\??\C:\some\directory`
   - `\DosDevices\C:\some\directory`
   - `\Device\Mup\127.0.0.1\C$\some\directory`
5. Restart the computer.

Another option is to use a VHD (or use a USB and skip steps 2 - 4):

1. Open **Disk Management**.
2. Open the **Action** menu and select **Create VHD** and follow the prompts.
3. Right click the new VHD (bottom half, right click on the gray section on the left) and click **Initialize Disk** and press OK.
4. Right click the data section of the VHD (bottom half, white and black rectangle with the text "Unallocated"), select **New Simple Volume...** and follow the prompts.
5. Right click the data section of the VHD and select **Change Drive Letter and Paths...**, click **Add...**, indicate the folder you want to mount the drive to, and click **OK** for the two boxes.

See also:

- [About VHD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323654.aspx)
- [How to Create and Attach a VHD or VHDX File in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9818-vhd-vhdx-file-create-attach-windows-8-a.html)
- [Assign a mount point folder path to a drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx)

Comment: Thanks; tested on Windows 7 and it works. Only way I could find to mount a directory that has a path beginning with \Device\Mup\

Comment: @petehern Which method was the one that worked for you, the **regedit** method, or the **VHD** method?

Comment: I used the regedit method.

Comment: is there a way to change the volume label for the registry option? It is confusing that the label of the source drive is used,

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The volume label can be changed from X to what ever label you want in step 3.  Step 4 you specify where the VHD is, so it has to be the source drive.

Comment: @Trisped you misunderstood 'volume label'. I did not meant the drive-Letter but the label that is shown in the explorer

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I don't know.  There is a mention of SUBST in the Wikipedia link, but that indicates that the source drive/volume must not have a label.  If I was you, I would ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the suggested ways, you could do one more thing. Share the folder and Map as network drive.
Here are the steps:

**Step 1: Share the required folder.** (You can just share with yourself or Admin group)

a.Right Click on the Folder and select Share with specific people

[image]

b.Click Share button on the share with dialog.

[image]

c.Copy the share path that is generated.

[image]

**Step 2: Map the network drive**

a.Click on Map Network drive in windows explorer
[image]

b.Once it launches, use the previously copied path as the network location.

[image]

c.Click on finish and you are done. 
 Make sure to click on Reconnect on logon.

Benefit is that you get to see the drive grouped separate from other physical drives.

Comment: Note that this requires Network Discovery to be turned on which you may or may not want depending on which network you're connected to.

Comment: This solutions has a few drawbacks, but I am grateful you mentioned it since it is a completely different approach.