# Path destination too long

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am in the process of trying to delete a folder from C:\Users but when I try and delete it, it tells me the folder cannot be deleted because there is a file name that is too long to go in the recycle bin. The catch is, it doesnt appear like there is anything in the folder. So since I have no idea where the file in question is, I cannot try and shorten the name. The box that pops up says destination path too long and shows a long file name with a bunch of weird symbols mixed in. I have tried opening a command window in this directory and used the DIR /X command but it does not show anything. I am running Windows 10. This has become extremely frustrating! Someone please help!

Comment: You can bypass the recycle bin using <shift><delete>. [How to Bypass Recycle Bin When Deleting Files on Windows 10](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/how-to-bypass-recycle-bin-when-deleting-files.html)

Comment: In File Explorer, click the View Tab->Options->View Tab->under "Hidden file and folders" , please ensure that "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" is chosen, press OK, and look in the folder again.  Just so you can see the file.  It's worth finding out if the file is important.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to use robocopy

Create an empty directory like `c:\empty`, then use `robocopy /mir /purge c:\empty c:\users\folder_to_be_removed`.  Robocopy can handle the really long file paths, and the `/mir + /purge` options will remove all the extra files from the 'destination' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another method in cmd is to mount a drive to a path using subst.

```
subst B: C:\deep\folder
B:
del B:\deep
```

From a related question :
[How do you mount a directory as a drive in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/109407/how-do-you-mount-a-directory-as-a-drive-in-windows-7)